# java ScheduledExecutorService как убивать зависший поток?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть вот такой кусок кода

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Aggregator(configurer, jdbcManager), 20, 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Т.к., пул потоков рассчитан на 1 поток, то, в случае его зависания, следующий поток запущен не будет. Мне же нужно при любых обстоятельствах запустить следующий поток.
Каким будет лучший выход для меня? Единственное, что я смог придумать, это переписать код на

```
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.schedule(new Aggregator(configurer, jdbcManager), 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(19, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

а затем поместить его в таймер с интервалом в 20 минут, т.е. в еще один поток. Таким образом, таймер будет каждый раз инициализировать новый `ScheduledExecutorService` , который в свою очередь будет ждать завершения выполнения потока 19 минут, если поток завершится раньше - прекрасно, если нет, то поток таймера в любом случае умрет, унеся с собой зависший поток из `ScheduledExecutorService`. Правильно же я понимаю, что если `ScheduledExecutorService` инициализирован в отдельном потоке, то со смертью этого потока умрут все потоки, порожденные `ScheduledExecutorService`? Будет ли всё описанное выше решением моей проблемы и какими могут быть более правильные решения?

P.s. Далеко не каждый раз поток из `ScheduledExecutorService` зависает. До первого зависания может пройти несколько дней. Предотвратить зависание потока на данный момент невозможно.

Comment: Никакие методы из `ExecutorService` не помогут гарантированно остановить поток, т.е. в принципе в java нет способа остановить поток, который сам не поддерживает остановку. Это значит, что вам нужно в первую очередь сделать так, чтоб поток правильно реагировал на [прерывание](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()), т.е. не игнорировал его и корректно заканчивал свою работу

Comment: @RomanKonoval, да, но если поток-родитель заканчивает работу, то поток-ребёнок , не зависимо от того, в каком состянии находится- тоже завершит работу, разве не так?

Comment: Нет таких понятий (и отношения между потоками) "родитель-ребенок". Если процесс остановится, то да, потоки все умрут.